# is arm64 better at compatibility than armhf?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, 32bit-64bit

I have raspberrypi4.
Current official Raspberry OS is 32-bit a.k.a armhf(armv7l).
I have some issues installing packages or using docker images and I think it is related to 32-bit system.
It seems like ARM architecture has less binaries compatible than x86. And 32-bit armhf is even worse.

So, what I'm curious about is...
would installing 64-bit version of OS help some compatibility issues with packages? I mean like there are few apt PPAs supports 32-bit. Will I be able to use more PPAs and install latest packages with 64-bit OS?

Any suggestion or guess is welcome.

Comment: This will depend on what you need, but generally, less people develop for arm than for x86 (or rather x64 nowadays), so there will likely always be packages that are not available for ARM. And since ARM64 is pretty new, at least for the Raspi, it's currently probably even worse, but it is to be expected that more and more packages will be made available for it. But it will always be the respective developers choice which platform they support.

Comment: x86 packages will not work on a Raspberry PI as far as I understand?  Just as AMD64 can run x86 32bit binaries, you can run an ARM64 system with an ARM32 user space.  It can effectively double the amount of storage as you need two versions of libc, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `arm64` is a better choice for wider compatibility with available docker images. `arm64` images are also able to use more than 4GB process memory.

As of 22 February 2022 on hub.docker.com:

- 123,643 `ARM64` images
- 69,567 `ARM` images

Update December 2022: With increased adoption of `ARM64` in the Cloud (AWS Graviton, Azure Dpsv5, GCloud T2A) I expect `ARM64` usage to continue to grow faster.